# Parallax Scrolling's effect staying in place instead of moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am attempting to add parallax scrolling to a page of mine and I am unsure of what I am doing wrong. This is how to set it up:

http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

I downloaded the library and put it in my file. I then called for it on the page, along with the jquery library. I then did this for my code:

```
<div class="home-img">
     <img src="/images/try.jpg" alt="">
     <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="/images/try.jpg">
          <div class="home-img-text">Quality Solutions</div>
     </div>
</div>
.home-img {
   /*position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;*/
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.home-img img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

That is what the instructions are saying to my understanding. However, I tried removing my base img line `<img src="/images/try.jpg" alt="">` and when I did that the img went away.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

This can be seen on my site, here:

[Click here](http://optimumwebdesigns.com/test_index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to load the Parallax.js library,
change to line:

```
<script src="/path/to/parallax.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/parallax.js-1.3.1/parallax.js"></script>
```

now the script will work.
But the "home-img" div will need to look like this:

```
<div class="home-img">
 <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="/images/try.jpg">
      <div class="home-img-text">Quality Solutions</div>
 </div>
```

This way you will be able to see the effect.
If you will keep the image it will be above the effect.

**EDIT**
I would recommend you use the browser inspect tools.
This way you can see if all of the javascript loaded currectly.

In your case the console tab in the inspect tool showed the error:

```
http://optimumwebdesigns.com/path/to/parallax.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

For chrome use this tutorial:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

For firefox use this tutorial:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector

Comment: cool. This worked perfectly. Instead of doing this: `.parallax-window {
   min-height: 600px;
    background: transparent;
}` How can I get the height of the image to be the natural state of height? I tried `height: auto;`, but that made the image shrink in height?

Comment: Basically what parallax do is to set up fixed divs at the top of the body. Then when the user scrolls to a div with a transparent bg, he(the user) sees the fixed div that the plugin adds. So sadly you will need to define the minimum height for the div if it doesn't have content.
You can put inside of ".parallax-window" the image with "visibility: hidden;" style, this way the div will have the original image size. But thats not the cleanest solution...

Comment: How can I get the content inside of that container? It only stays at the top of the div?

Comment: Sorry but i haven't understood your question. Basicly you have the fixed div below the content, and the transparent div(the ones that you add elements to/min height)("parallax-window") the transparent div just let the user see the parallx fixed divs. You dont have control over the height of the auto generated ones. I would recommend setting the div(""parallax-window"") min-height as the image-min height. Or if the div is empty, put the image inside with "visibility: hidden;", this way the div will be in the exact size as the image..

Comment: I'm sorry, disregard that. The height works fine, but in smaller media queries this gets all kinds of out of wack. Please see my site http://optimumwebdesigns.com/test_index ... In a 640px media query and below the parallax img takes over the div above it and the box-container div.

Comment: In the 640 media query, change the .box-container height to auto (.box-container{width:100%;height:auto;} and make sure that all of empty divs with <br><br>.. have background-color:#fff.

Comment: Cool. That threw off the size of my box-container sizes and made them small. Is there another way to fix that issue? When I was referring to the content within the parallax img, I was referring to the text you see over top of it. It won't adjust within the container for some reason. Why doesn't the parallax img move within my mobile view?

Comment: Sadly the parralex effect doesn't work well in mobile phones, you can that if you enter the website with a mobile user-agent it writes:Notice: Hello mobile user. Unfortunately, this parallax effect is not reliably achieved on mobile devices, so all you will see on this demo page are static backgrounds. Please visit this page on a desktop browser to see its full effect. |||| the effect just turns itself off when its detect a mobile phone user agent. But if you will re-size your browser it will continue working